# awakeFromNib vs didSet: Where to set Font or corner radius and why?

Tags: swift

I am trying to understand the difference between setting the `font` to a label or `cornerRadius` to a view in `didSet` of the outlet of `UILabel` or `UIView` vs doing it in `awakeFromNib`.

Which one is a good practice and why? Is there any performance or compilation-related reason?

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel! {
   didSet {
      titleLabel.font = UIFont
   }
}
```

vs

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   // Initialization code
   titleLabel.font = UIFont
}
```

Comment: As the label is an IBOutlet the best practice is to set the font in Interface Builder. A `didSet` property observer of an outlet is pointless anyway. And `awakeFromNib` make sense only if other *Initialization code* is executed. If you really need to set the font in code do it in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just setting a simple font:

```
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SomeFamily", size: 20)
```

then it doesn't really matter whether you do it in `didSet` or `awakeFromNib`. However, if your font depends on the property of some other `IBOutlet`, like (contrived example here):

```
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: anotherLabelOutlet.text!, size: 20)
```

Then you should definitely do it in `awakeFromNib`. In `awakeFromNib`, as it is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib):

> When an object receives an `awakeFromNib` message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.

In the `didSet` of `titleLabel`, however, it is not necessarily true that `anotherLabelOutlet` has been set. Outlets are set in a non-guaranteed order.

This not only applies to setting fonts, but also any initialisation that involves other outlets.

On the other hand, if you happen to *reassign* `titleLabel` somewhere down the line (for some weird reason), that new label won't get the font you set, if you set it in `awakeFromNib`, but will if you set it in `didSet`.

```
// in a later part of the code...
titleLabel = UILabel(frame: ...)
// titleLabel now has the new font if you set it in didSet, otherwise it won't
```

I would recommend that you don't think about this too much and just do it in `awakeFromNib`, and avoid reassigning `IBOutlet`s in general.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, people are fighting over this in code reviews :D thought I should get some experts advice as well.

Comment: @SharadChauhan Actually I forgot to mention, as vadian's comment says, the best thing to do is to set it in IB, but that's not always possible.

Comment: @SharadChauhan Note that `awakeFromNib`method won't be called if you create your object programatically

Answer (score 1):

Others have given partial information. Here is a description of the different methods you mentioned (as well as some others)

`awakeFromNib()` is called once after an object is loaded "from a nib archive". In modern iOS, that usually means a storyboard, although you can still load user interface elements from XIB files (the modern name for nibfiles.) This method isn't called unless the object is loaded from a nib archive.

`didSet` is a Swift language feature that lets you attach code to a property that gets run each time that property is changed. Use code in a didSet closure for code you want to execute every time a particular property is assigned a new value. That's the big difference in using this method: It only gets called when the property it is attached to is assigned a new value, and it will get called **each time** the property gets a new value.

The `viewDidLoad()` method is a method you can implement in your subclasses of UIViewController that gets called once, after your view controller's view hierarchy is loaded. This method is a good place to do view configuration that can't be done in a storyboard. This function must be implemented as an instance method of a `UIViewController` subclass.

As others have said, if you are using storyboards, setting your label's font in the storyboard is probably the better way to go.

If you build your view controller's view hierarchy in code, you'll probably implement the `loadView()` method to create and configure your view controllers views. In that case it would make sense to set their font and other properties there.

If you're using SwiftUI you'll likely configure your `View`s in the closure you pass into their initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the good practice :

If the features of the component you will create are not dependent on another component, using didSet is better in terms of code readability, but I do not think there is a difference in performance.

If you have too many components, typing the properties of these components into awakefromnib may affect the code readability.